Stepper Motor DRIVER Overheating
One of the issues in my project is the excessive heat generated by the TMC2130 motor driver I'm using, to the extent that it becomes too hot to touch and emits a faint burnt smell. I'm using a regular stepper motor, the SY42STH38-1684A, which has a rated voltage of 2.8V and a rated current of 1.68A. I'm supplying 6V to the VM pin using a generator, as my driver only accepts input voltages ranging from 5.5V to 46V. Additionally, I've limited the maximum current to 1A, and the motor operates properly under these conditions. The logic part of the driver is powered via the 3.3V pin of a Raspberry Pi.
In the future, I would like to keep the power supplied to the VM pin continuously without risking damage to the driver due to overheating.
Although I haven't really attempted any solutions yet because I don't see any except using the SPI mode that has an affect on the stand still current for exemple, I welcome any suggestions or ideas you may have. Currently, I'm controlling the motor using the step/dir mode. Would using a heat sink help mitigate this issue? I can't drop the Amperage limit or the motor will stop working.

You'll definitely need a heat sink (and ideally a cooling fan) on a TMC2130 on those current levels. 6V VM is also very little (3D printers usually use 24V for that); higher voltages will allow the driver to reach the target current quick which may also reduce thermal load.
You may also consider using a TMC5160, which can handle more current with less cooling.
Does the motor have to stay engaged during standstill? If not, you could disable it with the EN pin. No more heat, but also no holding torque.

Thank you for your response. I did plan to purchase a heatsink, but I cannot use a cooling fan due to the noise it produces. I will try increasing the voltage to see if that helps. The load on the motor is very light, but it might experience occasional movements due to external interactions. Specifically, my motor will be rotating a robotic bird's body and may receive pecks from live birds. Therefore, I'm unsure if disabling it would be in my best interest.

If possible, I'd use a mechanical solution in that case, like a worm drive. Even less load on the stepper, self-locking in the case of live birds trying to move it, and the higher RPM usually shouldn't be an issue for the stepper.
